# Flagged as duplicate no longer shows the link to duplicate question

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-history

Before the recent close reason change, a question flagged as duplicate is shown in the flag history like this:

[image: with link]

But now such flags no longer show the link to the duplicate question:

[image: without link]

---

Bonus: off topic flags now get a hyphen:

Before:
[image: off topic]

After:
[image: off-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicates now have a link to the duplicate.

Thanks for letting us know.

`off-topic` will keep it's hyphen, now that it got it (pretty much like badges, yeah?).