# Why was the space between "off" and "topic" replaced with a hyphen after the closing overhaul?

Tags: support, closed-questions, off-topic, post-notices

Here's the post-notice for an old question closed as off topic:

> ### closed as off topic by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers sometime before closing overhaul
>
> Questions on Meta Stack Overflow are expected to relate to Stack
> Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) within
> the scope [defined by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Consider editing the question or
> leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be
> reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about [reopening questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)
> here.
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help
> center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please edit the question or leave a comment.

Now, here's the new one:

> ### closed as off-topic by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers sometime after closing overhaul
>
> - This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the
>   software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) within the scope
>   defined in the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit
> the rules in the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please edit your question or leave a comment.

Notice the difference? The first one has a space between "off" and "topic", while the second has a hyphen. Is this intended, or is it an oversight in typing up the new close reasons?

Comment: Old off topic reasons presumably can't be changed without madness ensuing

Comment: Some people choose to hyphenate after a marriage

Comment: Neither is wrong, so I don't see a problem here.  Consistency with something that's obsolete isn't really important.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184382/flagged-as-duplicate-no-longer-shows-the-link-to-duplicate-question

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: As long as we're [warping the meaning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic), why not punctuate it funny, too?

Comment: @Antony How does that pertain to my question?

Comment: Did you read the answer by Oded? He said "`off-topic` will keep it's hyphen, now that it got it (pretty much like badges, yeah?)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Off-Topic" is used more often than "Off Topic":

[Meta search for "Off Topic"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22off+topic%22) - 833 results.

[Meta search for "Off-Topic"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22off-topic%22) - 1,901 results.

'Nuff said?

Comment: ["Off-topic" is more common than "off topic" elsewhere, too](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+topic%2Coff-topic&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20topic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20-%20topic%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, the hyphen is consistent.

It might not match the *old message*, but all the *current* flag option text uses a hyphen throughout, in the titles and descriptions when flagging.

Unless you are suggesting they are all changed back to the old way "off topic" which I don't think is as good.

While both are correct usage, being pedantic for the sake of it *off-topic* is better..
**off topic** are two words and could be part of a greater meaning in a sentence;
**off-topic** being grouped makes it clear, indicating one thing only, "off-topic";

It's all petty however, as while constancy through the site is good, I could mention 20 things which I'd prefer to be changed than this.

Comment: My question is not asking for change. I am just curious why there was a hyphen added in the closing overhaul.

Comment: @gparyani Who cares.  It could be as simple as a different person typing out the message with a different preference as to how to type the word.

Comment: @gparyani Well, you stated in your title that they "should be consistent", and I simply answered stating they already are. You also asked if it was an oversight, also suggesting you thought it was an issue, hence my answer approach ;)

Comment: @James I have edited my question. I was going to, but you answered before I could.

Comment: @RichardTingle yes, I agree.. but there are more important changes that could be made

Comment: @gparyani, your question edits makes most of my answer fairly redundant, and your question is now also a fairly trivial one...

Comment: That's because I am now asking for a response from the team...

Comment: Well, to be fair, you changed your question because my answer showed you were incorrect to state it was inconsistent. As I said, your question edits make my answer a bit redundant and appear like I'm answering your new question as if I know why Stack introduced the hyphen. But it's now a trivial question - ie who cares why they chose that - and the new question is one I wouldn't have answered.